# Add some data in aggregation with $match in MongoDb

Tags: json, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am using mongoDb, restheart and also new in these technologies. I want to add one more field in aggregation. So my exist aggregation working fine. I am sharing aggregation

**Aggregation:**

```
aggrs: [{
    type: "pipeline",
    uri: "by_time",
    stages: [{
            _$match: {
                bus::destination: {
                    _$in: {
                        _$var: "stands"
                    }
                },
                bus::eta: {
                    _$gte: {
                        _$var: "dateFrom"
                    },
                    _$lte: {
                        _$var: "dateTo"
                    }
                }
            }
        },          

    ]
}]
```

**Json Data:**

```
{
_id: "1938378_32323",    
bus: {
valid: true,   
eta: {
$date: 1500661200000
},
busDate: {
$date: 1500595200000
},
etd: {
$date: 1500661200000
},  
origin: "kalu",
destination: "cell",
},
apose: false
}
```

Above aggregation working fine, But I want to add "apose" in aggregation. So I have implemented this code for aggregation.

```
    stages: [{
            _$match: {
                bus::destination: {
                    _$in: {
                        _$var: "stands"
                    }
                },
                bus::eta: {
                    _$gte: {
                        _$var: "dateFrom"
                    },
                    _$lte: {
                        _$var: "dateTo"
                    }
                },
                 "apose": {
                    "_$eq": {
                        "_$var": "opposit"
                    }
                }
            }
        },          

    ]
```

But When I hit this aggregation, I got only

> {"_embedded":[],"_size":0,"_total_pages":0,"_returned":0}

My hitting url is

> http:...abc.../_aggrs/by_time?avars={"stands":["KALU","MAL","SALU"],"dateFrom":{"$date":"2007-12-21T01:30:00Z"},"dateTo":{"$date":"2010-02-15T09:30:00Z"},"opposit":"false"}

your answer is valuable for me. Thanks

Comment: url should be `...,"opposit":false}`. When you send `"false"` it is a string, not a boolean.

Comment: @Alex Blex. I also hit same "opposit":false. I have doubt in my aggregation.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the aggregation itself. To prove it you can try it with strings: add a bus with `apose:"test"` and search it with `,"opposit":"test"}`

Comment: According to you   "apose": {
                    "_$eq": {
                        "_$var": "opposit"
                    }
                } this is correct

Comment: Don't trust me =) test it. If it works with strings, it's a problem with variable type conversion, not with the aggregation.